# How to solve this kind of set theory problems?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $(S_1,S_2,...,S_m)$ is a finite collection of non-empty subsets of a universe $U$. Note that the sets in this collection need not to be distinct. Consider the following basic step to be performed on this sequence. While there exist sets $S_i$ and $S_j$ in the sequence, neither of which is a subset of the other, delete them from the sequence, and

(i) If $S_i∩S_j≠∅$, then add the sets $S_i∪S_j$ and $S_i∩S_j$ to the sequence;

(ii) If $S_i∩S_j=∅$, then add only the set $S_i∪S_j$ to the sequence.

***Steps i am taking to solve this problem are :***

I am considering the case where $S_i$ and $S_j$ have some elements in common then we'll delete both the sets from the sequence and will add $S_k = S_i∪S_j$ and $S_l = S_i∩S_j$ to the sequence now again $S_k$ and $S_l$ have some common elements and further the added sets will also have some elements in common and the sequence will goes on in an infinite loop.

Am i right ? Can we say that if this condition arise we can goes into an infinite loop ?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence does not loop infinitely. While $S_i \cup S_j$ and $S_i \cap S_j$ have elements in common, one is a subset of the other, and thus the "basic step" you describe cannot be performed on these two.

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in every step ? Is process always terminates ?